# Asynch download from URL iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asynchronous

Hi I want to ask for a good tutorial that shows me how to download a file from URL to local phone storage using objective C 
I have done the following its sync but i want to make it a synch

```
  NSString* docsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString* fileToDownload = @"data1.plist";
NSString* hostURLString = @"http://localhost/test";
hostURLString = [hostURLString stringByAppendingPathComponent: fileToDownload];
NSURL* pListURL = [NSURL URLWithString: hostURLString];
NSData* pListData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: pListURL];
NSString* filePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: fileToDownload];
[pListData writeToFile: filePath atomically: NO];


NSString* Path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *DataPath = [Path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data1.plist"];
```

Any suggestions

Comment: Try the following links. It may guide you to create and download asynchronously. 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820512/async-images-download-in-a-table
2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012612/iphone-downloading-data-asynchronously-with-nsurl-request-as-opposed-to-nsdata

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone: Downloading data asynchronously with NSURL request as opposed to \[NSData datawithContents ofURL\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012612/iphone-downloading-data-asynchronously-with-nsurl-request-as-opposed-to-nsdata)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is my code for async downloading images and data. You can play with it for your aims.

```
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        NSLog(@"Screen %@ - pauseBannerFileImage download starts", self.name);          
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:newUrlForImage]]];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:newUrlForImage]];
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"!-Screen %@-!pauseBannerFileImage downloaded", self.name);
            self.pauseBannerFileImage = image;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Using NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE) section of the [URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165-BCICJDHA) explains how to create an asynchronous connection, and also how to download synchronously.

Another option is to use ASIHTTPRequest, which can also do either synchronous or asynch requests.